# Form submits without required checkbox being checked

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox, required

I've been goofing aroung with my bigcartel onlineshop template for almost a week now, proceeding to edit an already existing theme to match my imagination.

In order to match my country's legal requirements regarding online sales, I need to include a checkbox which indicates that my customer has read, understood and accepted the terms of condition of my shop- to sum it up - the part that nobody reads at all :D

First, I tried inserting a checkbox with some text into the section and

```
<input id="agb_check" name="agb_check" type="checkbox" required /><span id="agb_txt">SOME TEXT.</span>
```

That however, didn't effect my submit button, but my "Refresh" Button which is used to calculate shipping costs, as soon you have selected a country.

Next, I tried to block the page from loading by adding a onclick event handler to my submit button:

```
<button id="checkout-btn" class="button" onclick="validiere()" title="Checkout" type="button">Checkout</button>
```

and added this script to my head section:

```
function validiere(){ 
    if(document.getElementById("agb_check").checked){
        document.getElementById("cart-form").submit();
    } 
    else {
        window.stop();
        document.getElementById("agb_text").style.color="red";
    }
}
```

Well- that didn't work out either.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

the site is: explore.dlld-fashion.de

Basically, the "checkbox required" pop-up which comes up when u try to recalculate your shipping costs would be perfect.

Thank you for your time and best regards from Germany!

Deniz

HTML Form code:

```
     <form id="cart-form" {% unless cart.shipping.enabled or cart.discount.enabled %}class="no_options"{% endunless %} method="post" action="/cart">
  <div id="cart_description">
    <section id="cart_items">
      <ul>
        {% for item in cart.items %}
        <li class="cart_item {% unless item.product.has_default_option %}with_option{% endunless %}" id="item-{{ item.id }}">          
          <div class="item_image"><img src="{{ item.product.image | product_image_url size:"thumb" }}" alt="Photo of {{ item.name }}"></div>          
          <dl>
            <dt><a href="{{ item.product.url }}">{{ item.product.name }}</a></dt>
            <dd class="item_price">{{ item.unit_price | money_with_sign }}{% if item.quantity > 1 %}<span class="item_quantity">(x{{ item.quantity }})</span>{% endif %}</dd>
            <dd class="quantity_input" style="display:none">{{ item | item_quantity_input }}</dd>
            {% unless item.product.has_default_option %}<dd class="item_option">{{ item.option.name }}</dd>{% endunless %}
          </dl>

          <a href="#" class="remove_item" title="Remove item from cart">Remove item</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}         
      </ul>
    </section>

    {% if cart.shipping.enabled or cart.discount.enabled %}
    <section id="cart_options">
      <ul>
        {% if cart.shipping.enabled %}
        {% if cart.shipping.strict %}
        <li id="shipping_option">
          <label for="country">Shipping</label>
          {{ store.country | country_select }}

          {% if cart.shipping.pending %}
            {% if cart.country %}
            <span class="no_shipping">We don't ship to {{ cart.country.name }}</span>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if cart.discount.enabled %}
        <li id="cart_discount" class="cart_item">
          {% if cart.discount.pending %}
            <label id="cart_discount_label" for="cart_discount_code">Discount</label>
            {{ cart.discount | discount_code_input }}
          {% elsif cart.discount.free_shipping %}
             <label for="cart_discount_code">Discount</label>        
            <p>{{ cart.discount.name }}</p>         
          {% else %}
            <label for="cart_discount_code">Discount</label>        
            <p>{{ cart.discount.name }}</p>
          {% endif %}
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>

      <div class="cart-update">
        <button id="update-btn-footer" class="update-btn button disabled" name="update" type="submit" title="Update your cart total"><span>Update total</span></button>
      </div>    
    </section>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  <section id="cart_summary">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Items</h3>
        <span>{{ cart.subtotal | money_with_sign }}</span>
      </li>
      {% if cart.shipping.enabled %}
      <li id="cart-shipping-tax">
        <h3>Shipping</h3>
        {% if cart.shipping.pending %}
          {% if cart.country %}
          <span class="shipping-amount">Select another country</span>
          {% else %}
          <span class="shipping-amount">Select country</span>
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          <span class="shipping-amount">{{ cart.shipping.amount | money_with_sign }}</span>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li id="cart-shipping-tax" class="not_set">
        <h3>Shipping</h3>
        <span>Applicable fees apply</span>
      </li>        
      {% endif %}

      {% if cart.discount.enabled %}
        {% if cart.discount.pending %}

        {% elsif cart.discount.free_shipping %}
        <li>
          <h3>Discount</h3>
          <span>Free shipping!</span>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li>
          <h3>Discount</h3>
          <span>-{{ cart.discount.amount | money_with_sign }}</span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      <li id="cart_total">
        <h3>Total</h3>
        <h2>{{ cart.total | money_with_sign }}</h2>
      </li>                              
    </ul>

    <button id="checkout-btn" class="button" onclick="validiere()" title="Checkout" type="button">Checkout</button>

  <input id="agb_check" name="agb_check" type="checkbox" required /><span id="agb_txt">Hiermit erkläre ich mich mit den geltenden AGB's einverstanden.</span>


  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: I think instead of `window.stop();` you should `return false;`

Comment: What type of language are you using on your server? You should never validate on the client-side since users can just change your JavaScript. You should send the data to your server side logic and check there if it's checked, a Boolean should do, if it's checked then continue with normal navigation if not then send a message to the user that he won't be able to continue if he doesn't check the box and stop the order from completing.

Comment: Can you provide the entire form HTML?

Comment: So this whole work arounds with JS don't seem to work. By clicking the submit button, another function seems to be triggered, which leads you to the checkout site. 

But what about fixing the connection between the submit button and the required attribut in the checkbox, which currently triggers the refresh button of shipping costs`?

Comment: ive posted the code in the original post!

Comment: Well.. it turned out that any of your approaches any even mine were right. As suspected, there was another jquery function triggering the redirect to the checkout site. 

Simply changed the btn id and adapted the custom code to the new id and it finally works! 

However, I can't sill figure out why the checkbox in the cart form is conditioned by the refresh button. But anyways- the workaround is sufficient. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your function to something like the following, it should work:

```
function validiere(){ 
    if(document.getElementById("agb_check").checked){
        document.getElementById("cart-form").submit();
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById("agb_text").style.color="red";
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that didn't work either. the button still triggers the link to the other side.

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/wQ99t/ . Maybe if more code is posted from your form/scripts we can debug it further.

Comment: ive just posted the html part of the form as an edit.Unfortunately, bigcartel doesnt allow editing the original javascript, which triggers a function which isn't stopped by the prevent.default code. 

the url of my site is: explore.dlld-fashion.de

Answer (score 0):

The validation function can be called from the submit button of the form. It should return false in case of validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
$("#checkout-btn").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

to prevent the default behaviour (submitting)

also, just

```
document.getElementById('theFormId').onsubmit = function() {                
            if(!validate())
                return false;
            }   
            else{
             return true;
            }
}
```

should work.

Comment: Ok, I just added a non JQuery solution

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. it still submits the form. :(

Comment: Does the form has the id? is the function validate() returning true if it is ok and false if it is not?

Comment: the validate() function does indeed work. the only thing which doesnt work is the stopping of the loading process